# Destroy all sessions but one

Tags: php, session-cookies

I have the same problem as this guy: [Destroy session, but keep one variable set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400474/destroy-session-but-keep-one-variable-set) (solved)

I'm trying to destroy / unset all sessions except one session named 'id' when a user logout.
I don't want to unset each session manually because I have many sessions.

This is my logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value) {
if($key !== "id") {
     unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
}
header("Location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

This code currently unsets all sessions and does not keep the session named ID.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you absolutely sure your value is stored in `$_SESSION['id']` ?

Comment: do print_r($_SESSION); before the foreach loop to check the keys => values relate as you expect.

Comment: `ID` is not the same as `id`, should that be the case.

Comment: @Martin I'm 100% sure that the value is stored in $_SESSION['id'].

Comment: then the logic in your exampled code should work. :-/

Comment: Yeah, I rewrote the code from the beginning in Notepad ++, Dreamweaver with no result. Could you perhaps try run this code and see if it works? I'm going nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign `$_SESSION['id']` instead of deleting all of the others.

A little trick :)

```
<?php
session_start();
$tmp = $_SESSION['id'];
session_unset();
$_SESSION['id'] = $tmp;

header("Location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Dude I seriously love you and I have no idea why this worked and my example did not. Makes no sense to me but thank you for the answer!

Comment: @DennisEnström Enjoy PHP:) Actually you can try `$key != "id"` instead of `$key !== "id"` also.

Comment: I tried that also but $_SESSION['id'] contains a token so I would like to check if it's "not identical" instead of "not equal" but maybe I'm wrong here also? ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
$keep_alive = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Destroy all sessions:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Set session again:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $keep_alive;
```

Comment: With this method, Do I have to start the session twice? The session is already started before session_destroy();

Comment: I think. You don't need to. I don't know exactly. That's why I am starting it again here.